# set content header name in response in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I write this following code to write jasper report in rtf format.It works well, but it open or save with default name file.rtf. 
I want to set the name as Report name.

```
        oConn = oPool.getConnection();
        ServletContext sServletContext = request.getSession().getServletContext();
        String sReportPath = sServletContext.getRealPath(sFileName);
        JasperReport jReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(sReportPath);
        JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, hParameters, oConn);
        request.getSession().setAttribute(BaseHttpServlet.DEFAULT_JASPER_PRINT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE,jPrint);
        response.setContentType("application/rtf");     
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=\"" +sReportName +"\"");
        RequestDispatcher oRequestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlets/rtf");            
        oRequestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: This should work fine. Can you check HTTP headers in the browser with Firefox or Chrome Dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check public [JRViewer](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/view/JRViewer.html#JRViewer%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)  - you can create JRViewer(java.lang.String fileName)

or setParameter - reference code

```
String fname= "fileName.jasper";
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(yourDir+"jasper/"+fname);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, fname);
porterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, nfl);
exporter.exportReport();
```